# How to send notification about AWS APP Runner status?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, amazon-app-runner

I'm searching for some way to send notifications when a specific app is deployed or updated on AWS App Running. I've already setup a rule on Event Bridge using following json, but it didn't work. Any thoughts?

```
{
  "account": ["$ACCOUNT_ID"],
  "source": ["aws.apprunner"],
  "region": ["us-east-1"],
  "resources": ["arn:aws:apprunner:us-east-1:$ACCOUNT_ID:service/check-gcp/$ID"],
  "detail-type": ["API deployed"],
  "detail": {
    "Status": ["UpdateServiceStarted"]
  }
}
```